# VBA (Excel): Run-time error '-2147467259(80004005)': Method 'Height' of object 'PlotArea' failed

Tags: vba, excel

I am running a subroutine in VBA, everything works fine except for one thing: at one point I wanted to change the PlotArea of a produced chart and I don't understand why I am getting the following error message: "Run-time error '-2147467259(80004005)': Method 'Height' of object 'PlotArea' failed".

The code is as follows:

```
Sub DTWO()
[...]
   Dim MyEmbeddedChart As Chart
   Set MyEmbeddedChart = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
   With MyEmbeddedChart
[...]            
      .PlotArea.Height = 200
[...]
   End With
End Sub
```

The strange thing is that, after getting the error message, if I press F8, that is 'Step Into', it does work perfectly. So, why the hell is this happening?

If you think you might need to have a look in the rest of the code, here you can find it:

```
Sub DiagramD2vsFields()
    Dim nPatients, nT, i, nOrgan1, nOrgan2, nOrgans As Integer
    Dim Organ1, Organ2, OrganN, PatientsConsidered, PatientsNotConsidered As String

    nPatients = Worksheets(1).Range("X1")
    Worksheets("OAR").Activate

    nT = 9

    Organ1 = InputBox("Column of the first organ:")
    Organ2 = InputBox("If there is, column of the second organ:")
    OrganN = InputBox("Name of the organ(s):")
    nOrgan1 = Range(Organ1 & 1).Column
    If Organ2 <> "" Then
        nOrgan2 = Range(Organ2 & 1).Column
    End If

    Dim TOTAL(), SP(), PP(), SFUD(), IMPT(), Mixed(), TOTALav, SPav, PPav, SFUDav, IMPTav, Mixedav, TOTALE, SPE, PPE, SFUDE, IMPTE, MixedE, sum As Double
    Dim nTOTAL, nSP, nPP, nSFUD, nIMPT, nMixed As Integer
    'Creating the vectors for Total, SFUD, IMPT and Mixed
    For i = 0 To nPatients - 1
        If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i * nT + 3, nOrgan1)) Then

            If Cells(i * nT + 4, 3) = "SFUD" Then
                nTOTAL = nTOTAL + 1
                nSFUD = nSFUD + 1
                ReDim Preserve TOTAL(nTOTAL - 1)
                ReDim Preserve SFUD(nSFUD - 1)
                If Organ2 <> "" Then
                    TOTAL(nTOTAL - 1) = (Cells(i * nT + 3, nOrgan1) + Cells(i * nT + 3, nOrgan2)) / 2
                    SFUD(nSFUD - 1) = (Cells(i * nT + 3, nOrgan1) + Cells(i * nT + 3, nOrgan2)) / 2
                Else
                    TOTAL(nTOTAL - 1) = Cells(i * nT + 3, nOrgan1)
                    SFUD(nSFUD - 1) = Cells(i * nT + 3, nOrgan1)
                End If
            Else
                If Cells(i * nT + 4, 3) = "IMPT" Then
                    nTOTAL = nTOTAL + 1
                    nIMPT = nIMPT + 1
                    ReDim Preserve TOTAL(nTOTAL - 1)
                    ReDim Preserve IMPT(nIMPT - 1)
                    If Organ2 <> "" Then
                        TOTAL(nTOTAL - 1) = (Cells(i * nT + 3, nOrgan1) + Cells(i * nT + 3, nOrgan2)) / 2
                        IMPT(nIMPT - 1) = (Cells(i * nT + 3, nOrgan1) + Cells(i * nT + 3, nOrgan2)) / 2
                    Else
                        TOTAL(nTOTAL - 1) = Cells(i * nT + 3, nOrgan1)
                        IMPT(nIMPT - 1) = Cells(i * nT + 3, nOrgan1)
                    End If
                Else
                    nTOTAL = nTOTAL + 1
                    nMixed = nMixed + 1
                    ReDim Preserve TOTAL(nTOTAL - 1)
                    ReDim Preserve Mixed(nMixed - 1)
                    If Organ2 <> "" Then
                        TOTAL(nTOTAL - 1) = (Cells(i * nT + 3, nOrgan1) + Cells(i * nT + 3, nOrgan2)) / 2
                        Mixed(nMixed - 1) = (Cells(i * nT + 3, nOrgan1) + Cells(i * nT + 3, nOrgan2)) / 2
                    Else
                        TOTAL(nTOTAL - 1) = Cells(i * nT + 3, nOrgan1)
                        Mixed(nMixed - 1) = Cells(i * nT + 3, nOrgan1)
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    'Creating the vectors for standard patients and pre-irradiated patients
    For i = 0 To nPatients - 1
        If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i * nT + 3, nOrgan1)) Then
            If IsEmpty(Cells(i * nT + 3, 1)) Then
                PatientsConsidered = PatientsConsidered & Cells(i * nT + 2, 1) & "; "
                nSP = nSP + 1
                ReDim Preserve SP(nSP - 1)
                If Organ2 <> "" Then
                    SP(nSP - 1) = (Cells(i * nT + 3, nOrgan1) + Cells(i * nT + 3, nOrgan2)) / 2
                Else
                    SP(nSP - 1) = Cells(i * nT + 3, nOrgan1)
                End If
            Else
                PatientsConsidered = PatientsConsidered & Cells(i * nT + 2, 1) & "*; "
                nPP = nPP + 1
                ReDim Preserve PP(nPP - 1)
                If Organ2 <> "" Then
                    PP(nPP - 1) = (Cells(i * nT + 3, nOrgan1) + Cells(i * nT + 3, nOrgan2)) / 2
                Else
                    PP(nPP - 1) = Cells(i * nT + 3, nOrgan1)
                End If
            End If
        Else
            If IsEmpty(Cells(i * nT + 3, 1)) Then
                PatientsNotConsidered = PatientsNotConsidered & Cells(i * nT + 2, 1) & "; "
            Else
                PatientsNotConsidered = PatientsNotConsidered & Cells(i * nT + 2, 1) & "*; "
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    TOTALav = Application.WorksheetFunction.sum(TOTAL) / (UBound(TOTAL) + 1)
    SFUDav = Application.WorksheetFunction.sum(SFUD) / (UBound(SFUD) + 1)
    IMPTav = Application.WorksheetFunction.sum(IMPT) / (UBound(IMPT) + 1)

    SPav = Application.WorksheetFunction.sum(SP) / (UBound(SP) + 1)
    PPav = Application.WorksheetFunction.sum(PP) / (UBound(PP) + 1)

    'In VB, for whatever reason, Not myArray returns the SafeArray pointer. For uninitialized arrays, this returns -1.
    If (Not Mixed) = -1 Then
    ' Array has NOT been initialized
        Mixedav = 0
    Else
    ' Array has been initialized, so you're good to go.
        Mixedav = Application.WorksheetFunction.sum(Mixed) / (UBound(Mixed) + 1)
    End If

    If (Not Mixed) = -1 Then
    ' Array has NOT been initialized
        nOrgans = UBound(SFUD) + 1 + UBound(IMPT) + 1
    Else
    ' Array has been initialized, so you're good to go.
        nOrgans = UBound(SFUD) + 1 + UBound(IMPT) + 1 + UBound(Mixed) + 1
    End If


    Dim nV As Integer
    Dim TermOfSD As Double

    sum = 0
    For nV = 0 To UBound(TOTAL)
        TermOfSD = (TOTAL(nV) - TOTALav) ^ 2
        sum = sum + TermOfSD
    Next nV
    TOTALE = (sum / UBound(TOTAL)) ^ 0.5

    sum = 0
    For nV = 0 To UBound(SFUD)
        TermOfSD = (SFUD(nV) - SFUDav) ^ 2
        sum = sum + TermOfSD
    Next nV
    SFUDE = (sum / UBound(SFUD)) ^ 0.5

    sum = 0
    For nV = 0 To UBound(IMPT)
        sum = sum + (IMPT(nV) - IMPTav) ^ 2
    Next nV
    IMPTE = (sum / UBound(IMPT)) ^ 0.5

    sum = 0
    For nV = 0 To UBound(SP)
        sum = sum + (SP(nV) - SPav) ^ 2
    Next nV
    SPE = (sum / UBound(SP)) ^ 0.5

    sum = 0
    For nV = 0 To UBound(PP)
        sum = sum + (PP(nV) - PPav) ^ 2
    Next nV
    PPE = (sum / UBound(PP)) ^ 0.5

    sum = 0
    If (Not Mixed) = -1 Then
    ' Array has NOT been initialized
        MixedE = 0
    Else
    ' Array has been initialized, so you're good to go.
        For nV = 0 To UBound(Mixed)
            sum = sum + (Mixed(nV) - Mixedav) ^ 2
        Next nV
        If UBound(Mixed) <> 0 Then
            MixedE = (sum / UBound(Mixed)) ^ 0.5
        Else
            MixedE = 0
        End If
    End If



    Cells(500, 500).Select

    Dim ER(5), ER1(5), ER2(5), ER3(5), ER4(5), ER5(5), ER6(5)  As Double
    ER(0) = TOTALE / 2
    ER(1) = SPE / 2
    ER(2) = PPE / 2
    ER(3) = SFUDE / 2
    ER(4) = IMPTE / 2
    ER(5) = MixedE / 2


    ER1(0) = ER(0)
    ER1(1) = 0
    ER1(2) = 0
    ER1(3) = 0
    ER1(4) = 0
    ER1(5) = 0

    ER2(0) = 0
    ER2(1) = ER(1)
    ER2(2) = 0
    ER2(3) = 0
    ER2(4) = 0
    ER2(5) = 0

    ER3(0) = 0
    ER3(1) = 0
    ER3(2) = ER(2)
    ER3(3) = 0
    ER3(4) = 0
    ER3(5) = 0

    ER4(0) = 0
    ER4(1) = 0
    ER4(2) = 0
    ER4(3) = ER(3)
    ER4(4) = 0
    ER4(5) = 0

    ER5(0) = 0
    ER5(1) = 0
    ER5(2) = 0
    ER5(3) = 0
    ER5(4) = ER(4)
    ER5(5) = 0

    ER6(0) = 0
    ER6(1) = 0
    ER6(2) = 0
    ER6(3) = 0
    ER6(4) = 0
    ER6(5) = ER(5)


    Dim MyEmbeddedChart As Chart
    Set MyEmbeddedChart = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
    With MyEmbeddedChart
        'Data
        .ChartType = xlColumnClustered

        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "TOTAL (n=" & nTOTAL & ")"
        .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Array("TOTAL (n=" & nTOTAL & ")", "Standard Patients (n=" & nSP & ")", "Pre-Irradiated Patients (n=" & nPP & ")", "SFUD (n=" & nSFUD & ")", "IMPT (n=" & nIMPT & ")", "Mixed (n=" & nMixed & ")")
        .SeriesCollection(1).Values = Array(TOTALav, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
        .SeriesCollection(1).ErrorBar Direction:=xlY, Include:=xlBoth, Type:=xlCustom, Amount:=ER1, MinusValues:=ER1

        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(2).Name = "Standard Patients (n=" & nSP & ")"
        .SeriesCollection(2).XValues = Array("TOTAL (n=" & nTOTAL & ")", "Standard Patients (n=" & nSP & ")", "Pre-Irradiated Patients (n=" & nPP & ")", "SFUD (n=" & nSFUD & ")", "IMPT (n=" & nIMPT & ")", "Mixed (n=" & nMixed & ")")
        .SeriesCollection(2).Values = Array(0, SPav, 0, 0, 0, 0)
        .SeriesCollection(2).ErrorBar Direction:=xlY, Include:=xlBoth, Type:=xlCustom, Amount:=ER2, MinusValues:=ER2

        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(3).Name = "Pre-Irradiated Patients (n=" & nPP & ")"
        .SeriesCollection(3).XValues = Array("TOTAL (n=" & nTOTAL & ")", "Standard Patients (n=" & nSP & ")", "Pre-Irradiated Patients (n=" & nPP & ")", "SFUD (n=" & nSFUD & ")", "IMPT (n=" & nIMPT & ")", "Mixed (n=" & nMixed & ")")
        .SeriesCollection(3).Values = Array(0, 0, PPav, 0, 0, 0)
        .SeriesCollection(3).ErrorBar Direction:=xlY, Include:=xlBoth, Type:=xlCustom, Amount:=ER3, MinusValues:=ER3

        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(4).Name = "SFUD (n=" & nSFUD & ")"
        .SeriesCollection(4).XValues = Array("TOTAL (n=" & nTOTAL & ")", "Standard Patients (n=" & nSP & ")", "Pre-Irradiated Patients (n=" & nPP & ")", "SFUD (n=" & nSFUD & ")", "IMPT (n=" & nIMPT & ")", "Mixed (n=" & nMixed & ")")
        .SeriesCollection(4).Values = Array(0, 0, 0, SFUDav, 0, 0)
        .SeriesCollection(4).ErrorBar Direction:=xlY, Include:=xlBoth, Type:=xlCustom, Amount:=ER4, MinusValues:=ER4

        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(5).Name = "IMPT (n=" & nIMPT & ")"
        .SeriesCollection(5).XValues = Array("TOTAL (n=" & nTOTAL & ")", "Standard Patients (n=" & nSP & ")", "Pre-Irradiated Patients (n=" & nPP & ")", "SFUD (n=" & nSFUD & ")", "IMPT (n=" & nIMPT & ")", "Mixed (n=" & nMixed & ")")
        .SeriesCollection(5).Values = Array(0, 0, 0, 0, IMPTav, 0)
        .SeriesCollection(5).ErrorBar Direction:=xlY, Include:=xlBoth, Type:=xlCustom, Amount:=ER5, MinusValues:=ER5

        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(6).Name = "Mixed (n=" & nMixed & ")"
        .SeriesCollection(6).XValues = Array("TOTAL (n=" & nTOTAL & ")", "Standard Patients (n=" & nSP & ")", "Pre-Irradiated Patients (n=" & nPP & ")", "SFUD (n=" & nSFUD & ")", "IMPT (n=" & nIMPT & ")", "Mixed (n=" & nMixed & ")")
        .SeriesCollection(6).Values = Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, Mixedav)
        .SeriesCollection(6).ErrorBar Direction:=xlY, Include:=xlBoth, Type:=xlCustom, Amount:=ER6, MinusValues:=ER6

        'Titles
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "D2%(%) of " & OrganN & " (Technique) [n=" & nOrgans & "]"
        .ChartTitle.Characters(Start:=2, length:=2).Font.Subscript = True
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Type of fields"
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "D2%(%)"
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters(Start:=2, length:=2).Font.Subscript = True
        .Axes(xlCategory).HasMajorGridlines = True

        'Formatting
        .ChartGroups(1).Overlap = 100
        .Axes(xlCategory).HasMinorGridlines = False
        .Axes(xlValue).HasMajorGridlines = True
        .Axes(xlValue).MajorUnit = 10
        .Axes(xlValue).HasMinorGridlines = True
        .HasLegend = False

        'Position
        .Parent.Top = Cells(nPatients * nT + 5, 1).Top
        .Parent.Left = Cells(nPatients * nT + 5, 1).Left
        .ChartArea.Height = 400
        .ChartArea.Width = 600

        'ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Activate
        'ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select
        'ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinorGridlines.Select
        'ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
        'Selection.Height = 270.46
        .PlotArea.Height = 200

        'ActiveChart.PlotArea.Height = 270.46
        '.Shapes.PlotArea.Height = 270.46
        'Adding textbox with the number of Patients included: expression.AddTextbox(Orientation, Left, Top, Width, Height)
        .Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 5, 300, 800, 20).TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Included patients: " & PatientsConsidered & "Not Included Patients: " & PatientsNotConsidered

        'Copy statistics data on the bottom of the table
        Worksheets("OAR").Cells(nPatients * nT + 2, nOrgan1) = TOTALav
        Worksheets("OAR").Cells(nPatients * nT + 3, nOrgan1) = TOTALE
        Worksheets("OAR").Cells(nPatients * nT + 4, nOrgan1) = SFUDav
        Worksheets("OAR").Cells(nPatients * nT + 5, nOrgan1) = SFUDE
        Worksheets("OAR").Cells(nPatients * nT + 6, nOrgan1) = IMPTav
        Worksheets("OAR").Cells(nPatients * nT + 7, nOrgan1) = IMPTE
        Worksheets("OAR").Cells(nPatients * nT + 8, nOrgan1) = Mixedav
        Worksheets("OAR").Cells(nPatients * nT + 9, nOrgan1) = MixedE
        Worksheets("OAR").Cells(nPatients * nT + 10, nOrgan1) = SPav
        Worksheets("OAR").Cells(nPatients * nT + 11, nOrgan1) = SPE
        Worksheets("OAR").Cells(nPatients * nT + 12, nOrgan1) = PPav
        Worksheets("OAR").Cells(nPatients * nT + 13, nOrgan1) = PPE
        Worksheets("OAR").Cells(nPatients * nT + 14, nOrgan1) = PatientsConsidered
        Worksheets("OAR").Cells(nPatients * nT + 15, nOrgan1) = PatientsNotConsidered

        Cells(1, 1).Select

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This seems to be a strange bug in Excel/PPT (and probably Word also) which requires some workaround to avoid the error. See solutions in the linked question, they should work for this problem.

Comment: I am sorry for the troubles: I wasn't aware of that post. Thank you very much for the information: I could finally solve my problem. I just think it's a pity that VBA is not more consistent than this...

Comment: No trouble at all, it's a strange quirk and I just wanted to point you in the right direction :)